# group by, order by and pick last value of a column in each group

Tags: postgresql, group-by, order-by

I am using PostgreSQL 9.6. I have one "events" table. I need to group by an "item_id" column then order by "date" column in each group and then pick last value of "value_num" column in each group. Pls, help me how this could be done.

Comment: provide example data and desired output.

Comment: Please add table schema, some sample data and the desired result. You can use some fiddle like dbfiddle.uk , rextester.com or http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: *group by "item_id", then order by "date"* OK but a group can have many rows and thus many different dates. Which one should be used for the order by? Or you mean that order is only to be used to find the "last" `value_num`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you want a "greatest-n-per-group" query. The easiest (but not necessarily the most efficient) way to achieve this in Postgres is using **[`DISTINCT ON`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT)**:

```
select distinct on (item_id)        -- defines the "group"
    item_id, date, value_num        -- show 1 row per group
from 
    events
order by 
    item_id, date desc ;            -- which order to be used
```